# How to render value in class based react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How could I possibly rerender the value of `SubmitState`, so that the `_setTooltipContent()` get the updated value of `SubmitState`

Here's the redux value of `SubmitState`

```
const SubmitState = useSelector((state) => state.SubmitState);
```

I have this class-based react

```
  class ElementEditor {
    constructor($element) {
      this.$element = findNearestChild($element);
      dispatch(selectedElement(this.$element));

      if (!this.$element) {
        this.type = 'empty';
        this.$element = $element;
      } else {
        this.type = this.$element.prop('nodeName');
      }
    }

    init() {
      //todo: if no innerText show uneditable option
      getTooltip(this.type);
      dispatch(elementType(this.type));

      $(window).on('keyup', this._onKeyUp.bind(this));

      this._setTooltipContent();
    }

    _onKeyUp(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        this.close();
      }
    }

    _removeListeners() {
      $(window).off('keyup', this._onKeyUp.bind(this));
    }

    _setTooltipContent() {
      if (this.type.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
        dispatch(selectedImg(this.$element.prop('src')));
      } else {
        dispatch(selectedText(this.$element.html()));
      }

      if (SubmitState) {
        if (this.type.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
          var img = document.getElementById('imgUrl');
          var imgsrc = img.getAttribute('src').toString();
          this.$element.css('height', this.$element.innerHeight());
          this.$element.css('width', this.$element.innerWidth());
          this.$element.prop('src', imgsrc === '#' ? imgValue : imgsrc);
        } else {
          this.$element.html(textValue);
        }
        this.close();
      }
      if (CloseState) {
        this.close();
      }
    }

    close() {
      this._removeListeners();
    }

    static isInsideTooltip($element) {
      return $element.parents('.se-tooltip-content').length;
    }
render() { return null }
  }
```

How I can use `componentDidMount()`?
Please help

Comment: You can have a `render() { return null }`.

Comment: I am very confused about what I am looking it.  Your `class ElementEditor` is not a React component.  It's a jQuery class.  You cannot use `useSelector` except in a React function component. You would use `connect` if this was a class component like `class ElementEditor extends React.Component` https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The useEffect can help you for **SubmitState** rerendering, you can see more information and examples from [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: but my code is class-based format I cant mix up class-based with hooks functional component

Comment: Hımm maybe this article helpful to you : https://glennstovall.com/how-to-use-useeffect-and-other-hooks-in-class-components/#:~:text=You%20can't%20use%20useEffect,entire%20class%20components%20writ%20large.

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    // Trigger update
    this.setState({ SubmitState: this.state.SubmitState });
  }
This can helpfull maybe,

Comment: how could I set it? like this? `this.state = {submit: SubmitState}` then `componentDidMount() {  this.setState({ submit: this.state.submit }) }` before `init()`?

Comment: I was suppose to use it as a `toggle` inside of `init()` but `init()` doesn't get the `nextstate`...